# How to write a recursive function without calling for raw input more than once?

Tags: python, recursion, raw-input

I want to write this recursively to encode other letters in the string with ord and chr, but when I write it recursively it calls for raw_input from user again. How do i fix this?

```
def rawEncode(input):
    input= raw_input("GIVE ME SUPER SECRET MESSAGE TO ENCODE")
    unencoded="%s" %input [:]
    if "%s" %input =='':
        return ''
    else:
        answer=ord("%s" %input [0])
        return answer
```

Comment: Put the input outside of your method?

Comment: @idjaw i did that it works

Answer (score 0):

It's better to get input and encode string in separate places. However you can get desired recursion by adding additional flag which disable input forcing and modifying return values to be a list for further concatting of ords:

```
def rawEncode(input='', force_input=True):
    if force_input:
        input= raw_input("GIVE ME SUPER SECRET MESSAGE TO ENCODE")
    if "%s" % input == '':
        return ['']
    else:
        answer = ord("%s" %input [0])
        return [answer] + rawEncode(input=input[1:], force_input=False)

print rawEncode()
```

Comment: From a pure design viewpoint I think it'd make more sense to have the function just take the input (as a required parameter) and have the caller put it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the statement
`input= raw_input("GIVE ME SUPER SECRET MESSAGE TO ENCODE")`
before the function call.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple

```
TempVar = 0

def rawEncode(input):

    if TempVar == 0:
        input = raw_input("GIVE ME SUPER SECRET MESSAGE TO ENCODE")
        TempVar = TempVar + 1

    unencoded = "%s" % input[:]
    if "%s" % input == '':
        return ''
    else:
        answer = ord("%s" % input[0])
        return answer
```